# How to dynamically change line spacing using IReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, line-spacing

I'm trying to change the line spacing dynamically using styled markup with variable in IReport.
This is how I attempt to do it, inside of my textfield

```
"<style lineSpacingSize='" + $V{linespace} + "'>" + $P{long_paragraph} + "</style>"
```

but it seems it doesn't have lineSpacingSize attributes, Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I would suggest you use [conditional styles](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-apply-conditional-formatting-your-text-fields) you can achieve almost the same thing (you need to define style for each linespace value)

Comment: I tried using conditional style but it seems line spacing is not working but font size, bold, italic, forecolor is working just fine